# Call to undefined method App\Models\Category::factory() laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the error stated above, and here is the copy log

```
php artisan db:seed

   BadMethodCallException

  Call to undefined method App\Models\Category::factory()

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:50
     46▕      * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     47▕      */
     48▕     protected static function throwBadMethodCallException($method)
     49▕     {
  ➜  50▕         throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
     51▕             'Call to undefined method %s::%s()', static::class, $method
     52▕         ));
     53▕     }
     54▕ }

  • Bad Method Call: Did you mean App\Models\Category::toArray() ?

      +3 vendor frames
  4   database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php:38
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__callStatic()

      +22 vendor frames
  27  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Here is the databaseseeder.php class since the error is there:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Transaction;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // \App\Models\User::factory(10)->create();

        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');

        User::truncate();
        Category::truncate();
        Product::truncate();
        Transaction::truncate();
        DB::table('category_product')->truncate();

        $cantidadUsuarios = 200;
        $cantidadCategories = 30;
        $cantidadProductos = 1000;
        $cantidadTransacciones = 1000;

        \App\Models\User::factory()->count($cantidadUsuarios)->create();
        \App\Models\Category::factory()->count($cantidadUsuarios)->create();

        \App\Models\Product::factory()->count($cantidadTransacciones)->create()->each                                                                                           (
            function ($producto) {
                $categorias = Category::all()->random(mt_rand(1, 5))->pluck('id');
                $producto->categories()->attach($categorias);
            }
        );

        \App\Models\Transaction::factory()->count($cantidadTransacciones)->create();
    }
}
```

There is the error line:

```
\App\Models\Category::factory()->count($cantidadUsuarios)->create();
```

Here we got the category class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public $table = "categories";

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
    ];
}
```

Here we got the category factory:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class CategoryFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Category::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            //
             'name' => $this->faker->word,
            'description' => $this->faker->paragraph(1),
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is the category migration:

```
<?php

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description', 1000);
            $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
            $table->string('status')->default(Product::PRODUCTO_NO_DISPONIBLE);
            $table->string('image');
            $table->integer('seller_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('seller_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

I am posting all you need since I am new to this and I cannot find the problem.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As of Laravel 8, you need to use the factory trait for the model to have the `factory()` method available.

```php
class Category extends Model
{
   use HasFactory;

   ...
}
```

Comment: I got `Fatal Error:  Trait 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory' not found` for Laravel 7.x

Comment: I assume a better way is to run seeds using `factory()` method after we define it for a particular model in `database/factories` folder. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/seeding#running-seeders

Comment: @nice_dev This trait did not exist in laravel 7. In fact the way to define factories was overhauled in laravel 8. For laravel 7, instead of using `Category::factory()->create();` you'd need to use the `factory()` helper like `factory(Category::class)->create();`. I recommend upgrading though. The longer you put it off, the harder it's going to be.

Comment: Fair enough, I will upgrade.  I presume that is worth putting a note below in your answer that is for Laravel 8 and above.

Answer (score 13):

Follow this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

add Trait to model => HasFactory

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Model extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if your using Laravel 8  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory is not there anymore, so just wrap your model class in factory() method instead

```
factory(App\Models\Category::class)->count($cantidadUsuarios)->create();
```

or

```
factory(App\Category::class)->count($cantidadUsuarios)->create();
```

Answer (score 0):

If at all you are using tinker, after adding Use HasFactory class, then simply end your current session and start another one.

```
- Ctr+c
- Php artisan tinker
```