# Error Laravel: Don't have view with extension blade: Call to undefined method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I create CRUD App, so far still good progress. When I want to make new page for EDIT, I got  an error

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\Student::id() (View: 
/home/john/Documents/api4/api4/resources/views/welcome2.blade.php)
```

I do read at this page: [Call to undefined method App\Models\Category::factory() laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68606726/call-to-undefined-method-app-models-categoryfactory-laravel)

I follow that advice, so I'm edit in file that contain

```
HasFactory;
```

but still error

I think, it not for my error or I just don't understand the solution.

this is my route

```
// Route for edit
Route::get('/editstudents/{id}', [StudentsController::class, 'editstudents'])- 
>name('editstudents');
```

this is in the continue

```
use HasFactory;
protected $tabel = 'student_id';

}
```

I hope you help me to solve this. Thank's

Comment: show code of welcome2 blade file as well

Comment: https://paste.laravel.io/3d568472-f2eb-45a8-b50a-cf411af7e862

this is my code Sir.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got some typo in your student model. Try to change this

```
use HasFactory;
protected $tabel = 'student_id';

}
```

To this code

```
use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'student_id';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your table spelling in model file.

It is given below

```
//Error Code: 
protected $tabel = 'student_id';
```

```
//Correct Code: 
protected $table = 'student_id';
```

Comment: Oke, I just edited, thank's